# What does it mean when a bool parameter is set to ? 1.0: 0.0?

Tags: ios, swift, boolean-logic

I'm following a tutorial and one of the parameters is a bool:

```
  func fadeImageView(imageView: UIImageView, toImage: UIImage, showEffects:Bool) {
}
```

but where the bool value is supplied in the body of the function the value is:

```
self.view.alpha = showEffects ? 1.0: 0.0
```

I was under the assumption that a bool can only have a true or false value.  What does this ? 1.0: 0.0 mean?

Comment: That is the ternary conditional operator : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html - `alpha` is of course no bool, it is a float iirc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.view.alpha` is not a bool property. It is `CGFloat`.

You have not assigned `Bool` to alpha property. The ternary operator in your example means, "If `showEffects` is `true`, make the alpha **1.0**, otherwise **0.0**"

Answer (score 1):

It's the [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID71). `a ? b : c` returns `b` if `a` evaluates to true, and `c` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on here, so I will answer both of them.

---

`view.alpha` is not a `Bool`, It's a `CGFloat` with valid values between `1.0` and `0.0`. For example, an alpha of `0.5` is 50% opaque.

---

`?:` is a special operator. Unlike `+` or `*` which perform an operation with 2 values, `?:` performs an operation with 3 values. This is why it's called the `ternary operator`. The first value is a conditional which will be evaluated as being `true` or `false`. The second value is the result of the operation if the conditional is `true`. The third value is the result of the operation if the conditional is `false`.

`<conditional value> ? <when true value> : <when false value>` is equivalent to:

```
func ternaryOperation(_ conditionalValue: Bool, _ whenTrueValue: CGFloat, _ whenFalseValue: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    if (conditionalValue) {
        return whenTrueValue
    } else {
        return whenFalseValue
    }
}

…

self.view.alpha = ternaryOperation(showEffects, 1.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: You might want to change: *"is an operator which does the following"* to *"is the ternary conditional operator which, in this case, would be equivalent to doing the following"*

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I think more clarity is needed.